# Como exibir dados de uma consulta no Modal?

Tags: php, html, input, button

Tenho um `button type="button"` e quero que ele capture informações das minhas *texts* para eu fazer uma consulta no *MySQL* e exibir esse resultado num *modal*. Porém, só estou conseguindo capturar esses dados num `button type="submit"` e esse `type="submit"` não abre meu modal.

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Podes colocar o `submit` no evento `click` do seu `button`: `<button type="button" onclick="javascript: <Apontar o form aqui>.submit();">Botão</button>`. Se servir, posta seu código que formulo uma resposta completa.

Comment: Poste o Código HTML e Javascript que você está usando pra caputar os dados e exibir o modal

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BNhQeucU

Comment: Eu achei uma solução, mas ele esta criando o modal dentro do while de exibição dos dados, ou seja, um modal para cada registro.

Comment: Não entendo a dificuldade. Você tem um botão Visualizar type="button"  para abrir o modal que funciona. Clica e abre o modal. No modal tem as informações, um botão Close (que funciona) e outro Save changes. Pq não usa button type="submit" nesse Save changes? Se houvesse um form no código haveria solução para usar  type="button" em Save changes.

Answer (score 1):

Em meu site uso os seguintes códigos:

> Nessa primeira situação uso a tag , onde guardo o id para fazer a consulta. veja:

```
<a href="#" title="Visualizar Pedido Por Inteiro" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-pedidos" data-id="<?php echo $idPedidos; ?>" onclick="mostrarModal()"><span class="fa fa-eye fa-2x" style="margin-INNER: 10px;"></span></a>
```

> É importante que você use o data-id, pois pode ocorrer, confusão na hora de mandar o código identificador na consulta, no meu caso o id.
>
> Pega o id do pedido mandado pelo onClick, carrega o conteudo da ff_pedidos_detalhados_php.php  com o id recebido e abre a modal

```html
function mostrarModal(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#modal-pedidos').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            var idPedidos = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
            var url = "../../componentes/php/ff_pedidos_detalhados_php.php";
            $('.modal-content').load(url, {idPedidos:idPedidos},
            function(resultado){
             $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
            });
          });
        });
      }
```

> Obs.: vale lembrar que ff_pedidos_detalhados é onde estão os selects, e toda a estrutruta que falta da modal, ou seja você tem que deixar na pagina que você quer abrir a modal, o "esqueleto da modal", veja como é a minha:

```
      <!-- ABRE A O CORPO DA MODAL QUE É CARREGADA PELA PEDIDOS_DETALHADOS_PHP.PHP -->
      <div class="modal fade validate" id="modal-pedidos" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- AQUI É INSERIDO O CÓDIGO TRAZIDO PELA CONSULTA -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- FECHA MODAL -->
```

Answer (score 0):

No tal botão se utilizar o `type="button" class="fazQuery"` pode utilizar query via AJAX em javascript exemplo:

```
    $(".fazQuery").on('click', function() {

        $("#modalId").modal('show');
        $("#modalBody").html("A carregar...");
        $.ajax({
            url: "urlProcura.php",
            data: {query: "Texto a procurar??" },
            success: function(resultado) {
                 $("#modalBody").html(resultado);
            }, 
            error: function(erro, resultado) {
               alert("Ocorreu um erro tente novamente.");
            }
        });
    });
```

No caso de estar a utilizar uma modal do bootstrap a função para abrir a modal é `modal('show')`

Exemplo de modal a utilizar:

```
       <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
           A carregar...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```